# Windows 10 update then can't connect to guest vm

Tags: ssh, windows-10, virtualbox, updates, putty

I'm a beginner in vm, I always used a working vm  :D  but today I've a big problem...  :? 
I've just updated my system windows 10 with the new available and suggested update, but now I can't connect to my guest vm.
Before (after windows update) I runned virtualbox  5.1.14 and it doesn't work, now I installed virtualbox 5.1.30 with the same result.
Before window's update it worked.

Initially I had one problem, host-only network doesn't works and the vm didn't start, so I deleted the old host-only network and created a new one and now the vm start, but I can't connect to the machine, that has a static ip (192.  168.  109.  151), with putty via ssh port 22, and also via http. 
I used this ip address to connect to vm via browser.
The vm can ping google, and in virtualbox command line I can log in and make everything.

Some one know why I can't connect with my vm?

In virtualbox preferences I have set host-only network  with this values:
IPV5 address 219.168.56.1
DHCP: 192.168.56.102
mask: 255.255.255.0
lower: 192.168.56.103
upper:  192.168.56.254

Comment: You might get a better response on this question over at [server fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

ok, now I can access via putty to port 22. I needed to add the static ip of the vm to virtualbox host-only network net in windows control panel, to tcp/ip protocol.

Now I need to acces via browser. For the moment it doesn't works